# rails model assignment with has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I just can't figure out how to create a relation with a join table. I've read all the posts about them, but the main error seems to be that in the join table to models should be singular, which I have. I just can seem to create the models correctly and assign them. I have projects with datasets, and projects can have multiple datasets, while a dataset can belong to multiple projects. A dataset can be active or not, which is why I need the has_many through instead of the has_many_and_belongs_to setup.
My model definitions are:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :activedatasets
  has_many :datasets, :through => :activedatasets

end


class DataSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :project_id, :filename, :tempfilename

  has_many :activedatasets
  has_many :projects, :through => :activedatasets

end


class ActiveDataSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :active, :data_set_id, :project_id

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :dataset

end
```

When I create a new dataset I've got the project_id in the params, so I'm trying to setup the relationship like below:

```
class DataSetsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @dataset = DataSet.new
    @dataset.activedatasets.project_id = params[:project_id]
  end
end
```

The error I'm getting seems famous:

```
NameError in DataSetsController#new

uninitialized constant DataSet::Activedataset
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction please?

Thanks for you attention.

Comment: Try `@dataset.active_data_sets.create(project_id: params[:project_id])`

Comment: try renaming your association - `has_many :active_data_sets` that should map to `ActiveDataSet` vs `Activedataset`

Comment: And also rename `has_many :activedatasets` to `has_many :active_data_sets`

Comment: By convention, the names like DataSet and ActiveDataSet generates relations named respectively `data_set` and `active_data_set`

Comment: Thanks MrYoshiji & house9. That got me going. Now I stil need to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
has_many :active_data_sets
has_many :data_sets, :through => :active_data_sets
```

And in the DataSet model:

```
has_many :active_data_sets
has_many :projects, :through => :active_data_sets
```

Basically, rails expects you to use underscores to separate words in association names, and converts them to CamelCase. So active_data_sets becomes ActiveDataSet. Rails then uses this to work out which model class the association is with.

You also need to change your controller to this:

```
class DataSetsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @dataset = DataSet.new
    @dataset.active_data_sets.build(:project_id => params[:project_id])
  end
end
```

Otherwise you'll get an error because you tried to set the project_id of the active_data_sets collection rather than creating a new ActiveDataSet.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I'm a bit lost however. I thought to understand the the models are in CamelCase indeed, and the database tables in snake case with the underscores and plural. Why do I have to use the database tables now instead of the models?

Comment: Confusingly, you're not actually using the table name here, you're naming the relationship. Rails infers the model name from here, and then the table name from there. As it happens the relationship and table name are the same in this example. It this had been a has_one relationship though, that wouldn't have been the case. Relationship name would have been active_data_set, model ActiveDataSet, and table active_data_sets (plural).